# how I extend setTimeout on nodeJS

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I want to shutdown my computer 1 min after I push button, and if I push button again it will shutdown after it push last time.

```
for(var i=1; i<=10; ++i){
 setDelay();
}

var nn;
function setDelay(){
 clearTimeout(nn);
 nn = setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("shutdown");
 }, 60000);
}
```

But my code have another "setTimeout" too. Will it work fine ?, or will it damage my other setTimeout ?

Comment: Why are you calling `setDelay()` in a loop?  That makes no sense.  `setTimeout()` does not block.  It sets a timer and immediately returns.

Comment: Just make sure it run just one time.

Comment: Then why are you calling it 10 times?

Comment: I want to extend it to 1 min every I call "setDelay"

Comment: When you say your code has another "setTimeout" - do you mean you are calling it somewhere else or defining it a new function named "setTimeout"?

Comment: I calling it somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you create an object that allows you to add time to it:

```
function Timer(t, fn) {
   this.fn = fn;
   this.time = Date.now() + t;
   this.updateTimer();
}

Timer.prototype.addTime = function(t) {
    this.time += t;
    this.updateTimer();
}

Timer.prototype.stop = function() {
    if (this.timer) {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
    }
}

Timer.prototype.updateTimer = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.stop();
    var delta = this.time - Date.now();
    if (delta > 0) { 
        this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
            self.timer = null;
            self.fn();
        }, delta);
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
var timer = new Timer(60000, function() {
    console.log("shutdown");
});

// add one second of time
timer.addTime(1000);

// add one minute of time
timer.addTime(1000 * 60);
```

Comment: Im try to run your code but it say, TypeError: this.fn is not a function

Comment: @ToszTemsong - I fixed a mistake that could cause that error.